# How to enable go support in doom emacs

Tags: go, emacs

I am new to emacs.I created a go file but there were no syntax highlighting,auto completion etc.

I uncommented  :lang go in init.el but it didnt do anything.I tried running lang: go.There was no option of lsp in init.el .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple Way

You can simply add the **go-mode** package to your `init.el` and you'll have the **code highlight** :

```el
(use-package go-mode
  :ensure t)
```

### Harder Way

If you want to do things like **auto-completion** or **refactoring**, you'll need the **LSP**.

- **At first**, add the following code to your `init.el` to use the `go-mode` package required for **Go** support and setup a hook to enable the **LSP** for it :

```el
(use-package go-mode
  :ensure t
  :hook (go-mode . lsp-deferred))
```

- **Then**, enable the infrastructure of LSP by adding the `lsp-mode` package to your `init.el` :

```el
(use-package lsp-mode
  :ensure t
  :commands lsp)
```

- **Finally**, add the user interface for the LSP :

```el
(use-package lsp-ui
  :ensure t
  :commands lsp-ui-mode)
```

Comment: it shows this error after i put those in init.el and used doom sync peculiar error: (void-function use-package)

Comment: @Neutral if you have this error maybe try to add `(require 'use-package)` too

Comment: after I used it it showed package not found but i was able to fix it using `
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

;; Bootstrap 'use-package'
(eval-after-load 'gnutls
  '(add-to-list 'gnutls-trustfiles "/etc/ssl/cert.pem"))
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
(require 'bind-key)
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)
`